# Group totals in F# - easy with sequences, is it possible with lists?

Tags: f#

Given a sequence of a group id/value tuples, it was easy to calculate group totals (pretty much the same way I would do it with C# and LINQ):

```
let items = ["g1",5; "g2",10; "g1",20]

let groupsums = 
    items  
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun x -> fst x) 
    |> Seq.map (fun (g, s) -> Seq.fold (fun acc x -> acc + snd x) 0 s)
```

But being new to F#, I can't see a way to so the same with lists. Do I have to use mutable variables, or is there a functional way to do the same with lists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built in `List.groupBy`.  A number of F# built in types have functions that are assigned the seq version of said function.  e.g. from `list.fs`

`let inline sumBy f (list : list<_>) = Seq.sumBy f list`

I'm pretty sure the designers of F# had many discussions about what to duplicate for the sake of consistency and what to omit for for sake of DRY.  I personally wish they stuck with DRY.

If you want to make your own "functional" List.groupBy I'd use map and list.

```
let groupBy list =
    list 
    |> List.fold (fun group (g, x) -> 
        match group |> Map.tryFind g with
        | Some(s) -> group |> Map.remove g |> Map.add g (x::s)
        | None -> group |> Map.add g [x]
        ) Map.empty
    |> Map.toList 

let groupsums = groupBy >> List.map (snd >> List.sum)
```

You can skip keeping lists if you only need the sum.

```
let groupAndSumBy list =
    list 
    |> List.fold (fun group (g, x) -> 
        match group |> Map.tryFind g with
        | Some(s) -> group |> Map.remove g |> Map.add g (x + s)
        | None -> group |> Map.add g x
        ) Map.empty
    |> Map.toList
    |> List.map snd
```

Output

```
> groupsums items;;
val it : int list = [25; 10]

> groupAndSumBy items;;
val it : int list = [25; 10]
```

Comment: I noticed there is no .groupBy ;) But maybe there is a way to do some kind of F# "magic" and avoid grouping at all? Also, in "to create my own .groupBy I'd use map and list" - what is the list? List have .map but there is no .list

Comment: @Sergey I added one possible solution.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think there will be a noticeable difference in performance or memory footprint?

Comment: I assume `groupAndSumBy` is the fastest.  Any time you use a bunch of built in functions to compose a larger function you will pay some kind of performance hit.  You pay this price in return for readability and speed of development.

Answer (score 8):

Although I would use kvb's suggestion, if you're going to roll your own, I suggest using `Dictionary` instead of `Map`. In my testing it was at least 400% faster.

```
let groupBy f (list:list<_>) =
  let dict = Dictionary()
  for v in list do
    let k = f v
    match dict.TryGetValue(k) with
    | true, l -> dict.[k] <- v :: l
    | _ -> dict.Add(k, [v])
  dict |> Seq.map (|KeyValue|) |> Seq.toList
```

Or:

```
let groupSumBy (list:list<_>) =
  let dict = Dictionary()
  for k, v in list do
    match dict.TryGetValue(k) with
    | true, n -> dict.[k] <- v + n
    | _ -> dict.Add(k, v)
  dict |> Seq.map (|KeyValue|) |> Seq.toList
```

By ref version:

```
let groupSumBy (list:list<_>) =
  let dict = Dictionary()
  let mutable n = 0
  for k, v in list do
    match dict.TryGetValue(k, &n) with
    | true -> dict.[k] <- v + n
    | false -> dict.Add(k, v)
  dict |> Seq.map (|KeyValue|) |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: +1, and you can eek out another 15% increase on top of that using the "by ref" version of TryGetValue (I saw @Jon Harrop mention somewhere that the tuple pattern match version incurs some extra heap allocations which I was able to see here testing `groupBy`).

Comment: Wow, this question becomes pretty useful for a F# noob like me ;) Thanks guys!

Comment: Map in F# is immutable and built on an AVL tree while Dictionary is mutable and uses a hash map.  Generally mutable data structures are faster than their immutable counter parts.  I used map in my answer since the question asked for a "functional" solution.

Comment: @daniel  I added the byref version.  Don't forget about list comprehension.  You can replace the last line with `[for kvp in dict do yield kvp.Value]`

Comment: @gradbot: Thanks. Is `ref` faster than usable `mutable` and passing `&n`?

Comment: @gradbot: I suppose `Map` does provide a more functional solution, but I would gladly give up "purity" for a 4x speed increase.

Comment: @Daniel no, I meant to use that instead.  I spaced.  ref uses the heap while mutable will be on the stack.

Answer (score 7):

While there's nothing wrong with gradbot's solution, I'd just keep it simple and use `Seq.toList` to convert sequences back to lists when desired.  So you could rewrite your definition as:

```
let groupsums =
    items
    |> Seq.groupBy fst
    |> Seq.toList
    |> List.map (fun (_,s) -> Seq.sumBy snd s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the shorter notation, but list is kind of artificial here.

Comment: @Sergey - while that's true, there's no real way to take advantage of the list's structure when doing the grouping, anyway, so you don't really lose much by using `Seq.groupBy` instead of writing your own `List.groupBy` (you've got to use an intermediate map structure in either case).

Comment: Unless you need only results of group folding (2nd part of @gradbot answer) in which case you don't need to keep the groups in memory. I think the best performance/memory solution would be folding a sequence into a Map.